# How to connect to Onedrive using MSAL?

Tags: onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to connect to OneDrive using MSAL token but it's returning error="invalid_token", error_description="Auth error"

This is my code:

```
    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read", "Files.Read", "Sites.Read.All" };
    AuthenticationResult ar = await App.ClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes);
    WelcomeText.Text = $"Welcome {ar.User.Name}"; //Login OK here

        //get data from API
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives");
        message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.Token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The direct API endpoint (api.onedrive.com) doesn't support access tokens generated from MSAL, only tokens generated from MSA. If you are using MSAL, you should use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io) (graph.microsoft.com) to access OneDrive files for both personal and business users.

Comment: It Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer long time back but I hope this link will be helpful for someone else in future. 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive